# Why am I receiving request with h/randomNumber.html

Tags: url, hacked-site, random

Recently, I've been receiving request spikes from requests of the form

```
example.com/h/<randomNumber>.html
```

Each time the random number is consistent (per 24 hours). On Google analytics I'll suddenly have 300% of my usual entire site traffic directed to a URL that I've no idea what it's attempting to direct to. When I go manually it 404s.

My question is, is this a known hack that indicates that my server is compromised in some way, or otherwise is this something that crawling bots might do?

Comment: Looks like a random attack for a specific exploit which you are not vulnerable to

Comment: I'm seeing the same patterns of traffic towards /h/*.html i.e. /h/9092612.html in Google Analytics. This should lead to a 404 page on my site, a WordPress site with Wordfence. Wordfence does not block these requests with the default settings. I've updated the Wordfence settings to throttle 404 requests.